# How to define consecutive values?

Tags: r

I have this example:

```
dat=c(2,1,1,2,3,4,2,5,6,7,8,1,2,4,5,6,7,3,4,5,2,3,1,2,1)
```

I want to assign values before the begin *[after the occurrence of 3 consecutive values with mean value > 3]* and after the end *[defined as the occurrence of 3 consecutive values  <3]* to NA.

Expected results

```
dat=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,2,5,6,7,8,1,2,4,5,6,7,3,4,5,2,3,NA,NA,NA)
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected result for the example data you provided?

Comment: The `zoo` package has a `rollmean` function which could help

Comment: I added the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rollmean` to find the 3 period means and `rollapply` with `all` to find consecuctive values which are all <= 3.

```
library(zoo)

r1 <- rollmean(dat, 3, fill = NA, align = "left")
i1 <- which(r1 > 3)[1]

r2 <- rollapply(dat <= 3, 3, all, fill = NA, align = "left")
i2 <- tail(which(r2), 1)-1

replace(NA*dat, i1:i2, dat[i1:i2])
## [1] NA NA NA NA NA  4  2  5  6  7  8  1  2  4  5  6  7  3  4  5  2  3 NA NA NA
```